# How to solve SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a line of code: df_empty.loc[:, "Address_Line1"] = df_empty["Address_Line1"].str.strip()

It is working perfect but showing SettingWithCopyWarning.

I have tried using :

df_empty["Address_Line1"] = df_empty["Address_Line1"].str.strip()

also tried :

df_empty["Address_Line1"] = df_empty["Address_Line1"].str.strip().copy()

but it did not solve the problem, still showing the same Warning

Comment: How is created `df_empty` before `df_empty.loc[:, "Address_Line1"] = df_empty["Address_Line1"].str.strip()` ?

Comment: If there is some filtering, use `df_empty = df[df['col'] > 10].copy()`

Comment: I have created df_empty = df.loc[df["Address_Number"] =="NONE"]

Comment: Use `df_empty = df.loc[df["Address_Number"] =="NONE"].copy()`